# Why I still didn't get the Full House hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

The **Full House** hat is described as:

> provide 3 answers with a score of 5 or more

Looking at my recent answers, I think I did:

- [Dec 18, score 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644119/sed-to-search-2-patterns-if-the-first-pattern-not-exist-print-the-second-patte/20644483#20644483)
- [Dec 18, score 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687881/merge-changes-on-detached-branch-after-git-checkout-commit-hash/20687992#20687992)
- [Dec 15, score 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598505/remove-a-line-contain-space-in-unix/20598529#20598529)

So, what am I missing? The 3 answers must be on the same day? Or they cannot be accepted?

**UPDATE**

This keeps getting downvoted. I guess because I should have re-read the rules before posting. I'll be more careful next time. Or is there more? Is there anything I can do to stop the downvotes, or is this a lost cause already? At this point I would rather delete this question, but of course I can't, because there are answers on it with votes.

Comment: Could you also link to them

Comment: @MartijnPieters He has 3 I just linked them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Winter Bash 2013 will run from Monday 16 December 2013 through Friday 3 January 2014.

Your first answer is from December 15, so it doesn't qualify.

Comment: Oh you ninja...

Answer (score 9):

> Winter Bash 2013 will run from Monday 16 December 2013 through Friday 3 January 2014.

The one on December 15th doesn't count.

Comment: @3ventic beat you by 54 seconds :(